# How to find out which side the mouse enter in RTL

Tags: jquery, right-to-left

I'm trying to find from which side of a div, the mouse entered to it (top, bottom, right, left).

I found a JSFiddle that works, but when I add it to a RTL website it returnes the same side, no matter from where the mouse entered.

Here are the JSFiddles: 
RTL: http://jsfiddle.net/jrsac08k 
LTR: http://jsfiddle.net/MJTkk/1

The JS:

```
function closestEdge(x,y,w,h) {
        var topEdgeDist = distMetric(x,y,w/2,0);
        var bottomEdgeDist = distMetric(x,y,w/2,h);
        var leftEdgeDist = distMetric(x,y,0,h/2);
        var rightEdgeDist = distMetric(x,y,w,h/2);
        var min = Math.min(topEdgeDist,bottomEdgeDist,leftEdgeDist,rightEdgeDist);
        switch (min) {
            case leftEdgeDist:
                return "left";
            case rightEdgeDist:
                return "right";
            case topEdgeDist:
                return "top";
            case bottomEdgeDist:
                return "bottom";
        }
}

function distMetric(x,y,x2,y2) {
    var xDiff = x - x2;
    var yDiff = y - y2;
    return (xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff);
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `offsetX` instead of `pageX`:

```
var edge = closestEdge(e.offsetX, e.pageY, $(this).width(), $(this).height());
```

See [RTL Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrsac08k/1/) and [LTR Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrsac08k/2/).